# Binding input value in unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a simple Angular component with text input which uses ngModel binding. the component works fine, but not the unit-test.

helloworld.component.html:

```
<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="name" >
  <p>{{msg}} {{name}}</p>
</div>
```

helloworld.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  templateUrl: './helloworld.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./helloworld.component.css']
})
export class HelloWorldComponent {
  @Input() name: string = "World";
  @Input() msg: string = "Hello";
}
```

helloworld.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from 
'@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './helloworld.component';

describe('HelloWorldComponent', () => {
  let component: HelloWorldComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HelloWorldComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HelloWorldComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HelloWorldComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should print the name on input', ()=>{
    component.msg = "Hi";
    fixture.detectChanges();

    var nameInput: HTMLInputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    var label: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('p');

    nameInput.value = 'John';
    nameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.msg).toBe('Hi');
    expect(component.name).toBe('John');
    expect(label.textContent).toBe('Hi John');
  });
});
```

The test fails because name is not set to 'John' but still has the default value 'World'. The provided code is in my eyes equivalent to the example in Angular documentation (https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-binding)

There are some articles that explain to perform the test in async() and use fixture.whenStable().then() after changing the input value.

I also found the hint to run the test inside fakeAsync() and use tick() to wait for the input value to be bound to name. Both didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: try using `tick(); fixture.detectChanges();` after `fixture.detectChanges();` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help either.